# Conditional Query To Determine The Status of My Reports

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a View that needs to Calculate the Status of a Report. However its getting a little complex and looking for some help.

Example Data:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZpQ95/4/

In that example,

Report 1 would be Approved

Report 2 would be Denied

Report 3 would be Pending

Report 4 would be Draft

Basically I need to create the Status Column for this.

1. If all 5 roles have approved (2) then the report is Approved.
2. If there are NO approval records then the report is a draft (1).
3. If there are some approvals (2) and no denies (3) then the report is Pending
4. If there is one denied (3) approval then the report is denied.

c# example of #1 - Approved:

```
JobRoles.All(j => report.Approvals.Any(a => a.Role == j && a.Status == Approvals.Approved))
```

c# Example of #2 - Draft

```
report.Approvals.Count == 0
```

c# Example of #3 - Pending

```
!report.Approvals.Any(s => s.Status == Approvals.Denied) && report.Approvals.Count > 0
```

c# Example of #4 - Denied

```
report.Approvals.Count > 0 && report.Approvals.Any(s => s.Status == Approvals.Denied)
```

It will be a sub query on my main query which loops through all the reports:

```
SELECT Id, FromDate, ToDate,
(Status) FROM dbo.Reports AS EX
WHERE  (IsDeleted = 0)
```

Status table is called: dbo.Approvals

SQL Server 2012

Thanks :D
~ Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a report table as well as an approval table in order to capture tables that have no Approvals.
So my solution looked like this. Here is my SQLFiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78070

```
select Reports.Report_id
,case
when exists(select * from Approvals Denied where 
               Denied.Report_id = Reports.Report_id
               and Denied.Status = 3)then
  'Denied'
when (Select count(Approvals.Report_id))=0 then
  'Draft'
when (Select count(Approvals.Report_id))<>5 then
  'Pending'
when (Select count(Approvals.Report_id))=5 then
  'Approved'
end
from Reports
left outer join Approvals
  on Reports.Report_id = Approvals.Report_id

group by
Reports.Report_id
```